# Arabic language in .htm files

Tags: language-support

- I have a .swf (and another .htm) video with comments in arabic, but when i open it the words are reversed , how to solve this and thanks .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking about right-to-left text direction, which can be used by adding `dir="rtl"` to the `html` tag of your document.

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Comment: i am sorry , but what i mean is that the characters of the word themselves are reversed .